# Is there a way to render HTML code that is written in an ACE editor

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor

I am working on a React app that uses ACE as a code editor. I would like the user to input their HTML into the editor and click a run button to render that HTML on a split screen, much like Codepen. I don't really know where to start.

I have messed around with ACE in a side project but want to flesh it out more before implementing it into my Main project so I do't break anything.

```
<AceEditor
            placeholder="Placeholder Text"
            mode="javascript"
            theme="monokai"
            name="blah2"
            onLoad={onLoad}
            onChange={onChange}
            fontSize={14}
            showPrintMargin={true}
            showGutter={true}
            highlightActiveLine={false}
            value={`function onLoad(editor) {
  console.log("i've loaded");
}`}
            setOptions={{
              enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
              enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
              enableSnippets: true,
              showLineNumbers: true,
              tabSize: 2
            }}
          />
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Look for how to parse an html string and then just render it (save it as state)

Comment: There are multiple libraries that will take HTML and React-ify it in addition to the (deprecated) dangerouslySetInnerHtml or whatever it was called.